# Subir multiples Imagenes en Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy intentando subir multiples imagenes en una formulario de django. Hasta el momento llegue al punto de obtener este error `InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'get'` indicando que el problema es en la linea  `imgform.save()` de la vista.

Este es mi código simplificado:

## realstate.models

```
from django.db import models

class Property(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class PropertyImage(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField()
```

## realstate.forms

```
from realstate.models import Property, PropertyImage

class AddPropertyForm(forms.ModelForm):

        model = Property
        fields = '__all__'

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].widget.attrs['multiple'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = PropertyImage
        fields = '__all__'
```

## realstate.views

```
def add_property(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddPropertyForm(request.POST)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('image')
        print(files)
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                imgform = ImageForm(f)
                if imgform.is_valid:
                    imgform.save()
            form.save()
        return HttpResponse("image upload success")
    else:
        form = AddPropertyForm()
        imgform = ImageForm()

    return render(request, 'realstate/admin-property-add.html', {'form': form, 'imgform': imgform})
```

## template

```
<form action="{% url 'realstate:add-property' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.title }}
    {{ imgform.image }}
</form>
```

El debug dice que el error es en la vista al momento de hacer `imgform.save`, pero sinceramente no tengo claro como proceder porque generalmente las soluciones que he encontrado dicen algo como:

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('image')
for f in files:
  #Haz algo con file...
```

Y ahí esta el detalle, no se que es lo que tengo que hacer con `file` para que me lo guarde en la base de datos.

Comment: lo que yo creo que pasa es que no le estas pasando los datos correctamente al formulario de imagenes,  debes ser especifico y decirle que recibirá archivos por lo cual deberias pasarlos asi: `imgform = ImageForm(files=request.FILES)`, pero como estas en un bucle, quizas pueda servirte `ImageForm(initial={'image': f})` o intenta pasar asi el mismo diccionario, solo que no con `initial` si no con `files`

Comment: tienes algún ejemplo donde pueda buscar más información?

Answer (score 2):

De esta manera se guardan las imagenes

```
class ImagenCreateView(CreateView):
        model = imagen
        fields = "__all__"

        def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save()
            files = [serialize(self.object)]
            data = {'files': files}
            response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
            return response

        def form_invalid(self, form):
            data = json.dump(form.errors)
            return HttpResponse(content=data, status=400, content_type='application/json')
```

Y este es mi response

```
# encoding: utf-8
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

MIMEANY = '*/*'
MIMEJSON = 'application/json'
MIMETEXT = 'text/plain'


def response_mimetype(request):
    """response_mimetype -- Return a proper response mimetype, accordingly to
    what the client accepts, as available in the `HTTP_ACCEPT` header.

    request -- a HttpRequest instance.

    """
    can_json = MIMEJSON in request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']
    can_json |= MIMEANY in request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']
    return MIMEJSON if can_json else MIMETEXT


class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """JSONResponse -- Extends HTTPResponse to handle JSON format response.

    This response can be used in any view that should return a json stream of
    data.

    Usage:

        def a_iew(request):
            content = {'key': 'value'}
            return JSONResponse(content, mimetype=response_mimetype(request))

    """
    def __init__(self, obj='', json_opts=None, mimetype=MIMEJSON, *args, **kwargs):
        json_opts = json_opts if isinstance(json_opts, dict) else {}
        content = json.dumps(obj, **json_opts)
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, mimetype, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Pensé que corrigiendo alguna parte de mi vista original se arreglaría el problema, pero si esta es la solución real te agradecería si dieras un poco más de contexto, porque la verdad se muy poco de `class based views`.